I created a measure in power bi, it's not distributed over a certain code in a matrix visual, using 3 tables one to one & one to many relationships
I need help & I think a planning engineer would easily understand the situation.
I've 3 tables, named TActDB, TCodes & TAPerc.

TActDB linked to TCodes by one to one both direction relation via column named "Activity ID" (Unique).

TActDB linked to TAPerc by one to many relationship via same column "Activity ID" (See Pic #1).

in table TAPerc I've created a measure "Cum EMH" (i.e.: Cumulative Earned Manhour = ∑EMH) with the below DAX.
Cum EMH = IF(SUM(TAPerc[EMH])=0,BLANK(),CALCULATE(SUM(TAPerc[EMH]),FILTER(ALL(TAPerc),TAPerc[DDate]<=MAX(TDate[Date]))))

now the issue is when i used a matrix visual it couldn't distribute the Cum EMH over the building, noting that building is a column under the table TCodes (see Pic #2).


I tried having the one to many relationship to be both directions and single, but either didn't work.
I don't know why it's unable to distribute the Cum EMH over the buildings and how to resolve the issue.

Forgot to mention, there's a 4th table "Date table" which I use to filter date thru a slicer. And the TAPerc have the progress under each date (weekly basis), and have been unpivot during the power query. This is why in the DAX above I used "All(Table)" to supersede any filtered dates and then want it to apply the calculations as long as the date is <= the max applied date in the slicer.
